# How to pass an argument into propertyChange?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

So the title is pretty self explanatory.

`<Switch *ngIf="item.type=='checkbox'" [item]="item" (propertyChange)="onAttributeSwitchChange" row="1" checked="false"></Switch>`

```
public onAttributeSwitchChange(args: observable.PropertyChangeData) {
  console.dir(args);

  //console.log(args.propertyName + " has been changed and the new value is: " + args.value);
  if (args.propertyName === "checked") {
  } else {

  }
}
```

I need to get the `item` into the `onAttributeSwitchChange`
And also, i need to make `onAttributeSwitchChange` working, because its not now(When i change value the `console.dir` doesn't fire).

Reference: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1353

Comment: try to `console.dir(args.object)`

Comment: to access the component value in NativeScript Angular project you should also add id to the element and to set the argument in the method like: `FirstCheckChange(sw1.checked`. Example: `<Switch #sw1 [checked]="FirstSwitchValue" (checkedChange)="FirstCheckChange(sw1.checked)" row="0" col="1"></Switch>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @alexis-cramatte for the tip :)

But here's what worked:

In (Nativescript) NG2 you can access the properties by the ID.
`<Switch #switch *ngIf="item.type=='checkbox'" row="1" checked="false" (checkedChange)="onAttributeSwitchChange(switch.checked)"></Switch>`

## switch - Sets the ID

and then you can use the properties of the object by - switch.[propertyhere] - for example: switch.checked

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried but according to [nativescript-sdk-examples-ng](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/switch/basic-switch) it should probably look something like this:

my-switch.html

```
<Switch *ngIf="item.type=='checkbox'" [item]="item" (checkedChange)="onAttributeSwitchChange(item)" row="1" [checked]="switchValue"></Switch>
```

mySwitchComponent.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "switch-stuff",
    templateUrl: "some/path/my-switch.html",
})
export class MySwitchComponent {

    switchValue: boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    onAttributeSwitchChange(item) {
        //do something with item here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can i know when it's checked and not checked?

Comment: The Switch is dinamicly generated.. so the [checked, kinda doesnt work]